# Moq Returns method returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking

I'm new to Moq and trying to get my mock to return a value in ASP.NET MVC. Docs [here](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/IReturns(TMock,TResult)/M/Returns(T)). Code:

```
mock = new Mock<IRepository<Story>>();

mock.Setup(x => x.GetById( It.Is<int>( i => i==10 ) ))
    .Returns(It.Is<Story>((Story story) => story.Id == 10 && story.Hits == 0));

storiesController = new StoriesController(mock.Object);

ViewResult result = storiesController.Details(10) as ViewResult;
```

and `Details` method calls `storyRepository.GetById(id)`

and this test fails:  `Assert.IsNotNull(result);` because `GetById` method returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Story story = storyRepository.GetById(id);
            if (story == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            story.Hits++; // TODO!
            storyRepository.Update(story);
            storyRepository.Save();
            return View(story);
        }
```

This is the Details method. In debug mode I see the fetched Story is null as soon as I step over the called GetById method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is ocurred because `Returns` was the result not a assert change to :

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetById(10) ))
    .Returns(new Story {Id=10 });
```

Comment: Will do as soon as I can, it says I can mark in 5 minutes

Comment: @Johnath Ok, Just not forget .